# On updating an image url the image doesn't get rendered on frontend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have written a directive that renders screenshot of a page, if a screenshot is available else it shows a placeholder.

```
commonDirectives.directive("showScreenShot", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope:{},
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var template = '';
        if(attrs.url){
            template += '<div><img src=' + attrs.url + '></div>';
        }
        else{
            template += '<div class="placeholder"></div>'
        }
        element.replaceWith(template)
    }
}
})
```

It is able to render the image properly the first time but the second time rendering fails. It is unable to show the image. I don't understand why it is unable to render image even though the image url points to right image.

**UPDATE**

What if I want to do something like re-render an image after a timewait of say 10 secs, I can't use $watch because the URl remains the same, but the image at the given url gets updated after 10 secs:

```
commonDirectives.directive("showScreenShot",['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope:{
        url: '@'
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="!url" class="dbimg placeholder">' +
    '<div class="phicons">' +
    '   <i class="phicn icon2-bars-3 p1"></i>' +
    '   <i class="phicn icon2-stats p2"></i>' +
    '   <i class="phicn icon2-graph p3"></i>' +
    '   <i class="phicn fa fa-table p4"></i>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>',
    link: function(scope, ele, attrs) {
        var template;
        if(attrs.url){
            template = '<div class="snapshotmsg">Generating preview ...</div><div class="dbimg placeholder">';
            $timeout(function () {
                template = '<div class="db_img"><img ng-src="' + attrs.url + '"></div>'
                ele.replaceWith(template)
            }, 10000);
            ele.replaceWith(template)
        }
    }
}
```

}]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `link` function runs (when the directive is first compiled), the template that you generate is added to the DOM. Later, when you change the `url` attribute there is nothing that triggers a change in the DOM.

The easiest way to go would be to use an isolate scope property of `url` rather than an attribute. You won't even need a `link` function if you just template your directive smartly by re-using built-in directives.

```
.directive("showScreenShot", function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope:{
       url: "@"
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="url"><img ng-src="{{url}}"/></div>' + 
              '<div ng-if="!url" class="placeholder"></div>'
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use :- ng-src

```
 template += '<div><img ng-src=' + attrs.url + '></div>';
```